# Generate tree view using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to generate tree view using jQuery and JSON.

My JSON(single folder):

```
[{"id":"076ac97d","path":"\/test\/undefined","name":"undefined","parentDirName":"test","parentDirId":"70b77ddd-6c15"}, .... ]
```

When folder is in root, parentDirId key has empty value: "", if is in catalog, has a parent ID.

I want to generate ul li list tree.

Do you have an idea how to iterate in this JSON and append ul li list to html?

I have an AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",

    success: function(response){
    //code
    }
```

How to generate dir tree? Firstly append dirs to dirs with parentID.

Comment: Can you add example input and output?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function below. It first creates a new object structure keyed by `id`, which allows quick lookup of the parent of each node. At the same time it creates an `LI` element for each of them, together with an empty `UL` element. Finally all these `LI` and `UL` elements are linked together according to the parent-child relationship:

```js
function populateUL($ul, data) {
    // Register the given UL element as the root in a new data structure
    var hash = { 
        "": { $ul: $ul }
    };
    // Key the objects by their id, and create individual LI elements for them,
    // and an empty UL container for their potential child elements
    data.forEach(function (o) {
        var $ul = $("<ul>");
        hash[o.id] = { 
            $ul: $ul,
            $li: $("<li>").text(o.name).append($ul)
        };
    });
    // Append each LI element to the correct parent UL element
    data.forEach(function (o) {
        hash[o.parentDirId].$ul.append(hash[o.id].$li);
    });
}

// Sample response object
var response = [{
    "id":"70b77ddd-6c15",
    "path":"/test",
    "name":"test",
    "parentDirName":"",
    "parentDirId":""
}, {
    "id":"076ac97d",
    "path":"/test/chess",
    "name":"chess",
    "parentDirName":"test",
    "parentDirId":"70b77ddd-6c15"
}, {
    "id":"076ac97e",
    "path":"/test/bingo",
    "name":"bingo",
    "parentDirName":"test",
    "parentDirId":"70b77ddd-6c15"
}, {
    "id":"076ac97f",
    "path":"/test/chess/major pieces",
    "name":"major pieces",
    "parentDirName":"chess",
    "parentDirId":"076ac97d"
}, {
    "id":"076ac97g",
    "path":"/test/chess/major pieces/rook",
    "name":"rook",
    "parentDirName":"major pieces",
    "parentDirId":"076ac97f"
}, {
    "id":"076ac97h",
    "path":"/test/chess/major pieces/queen",
    "name":"queen",
    "parentDirName":"major pieces",
    "parentDirId":"076ac97f"
}, {
    "id":"076b0000",
    "path":"/test/chess/minor pieces",
    "name":"minor pieces",
    "parentDirName":"chess",
    "parentDirId":"076ac97d"
}, {
    "id":"076b0001",
    "path":"/test/chess/minor pieces/knight",
    "name":"knight",
    "parentDirName":"minor pieces",
    "parentDirId":"076b0000"
}, {
    "id":"076b0002",
    "path":"/test/chess/minor pieces/bishop",
    "name":"bishop",
    "parentDirName":"minor pieces",
    "parentDirId":"076b0000"
}];

// Inject response data into document
populateUL($("#root"), response);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="root"></ul>
```

For this to work, the root element *must* be referenced by an empty string for *parentDirId*.

Note that the properties *path* and *parentDirName* are not used in this algorithm, since they contain information that is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean something like this

```js
function listItem(obj) {
  var html = "<ul>"
  jQuery.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    html += "<li>" + key + ':'
    if (typeof value !== "object")
      html += value
    else
      html += listItem(value)
    html += "</li>"
  })
  return html + "</ul>"
}

var obj = {
  "id": "076ac97d",
  "rawr": {
    "mew": 2
  },
  "path": "\/test\/",
  "name ": "undefined",
  "parentDirName ": "test",
  "parentDirId ": "70 b77ddd "
};
document.write(listItem(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't edit JSON to "rawr": { "mew": 2 } :( I had an idea: append all items with parentDir "" and add class ID, in second step, append dirs which same parentpath as appended item class. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Dominik The "rawr" is just added to show how nested objects would be handled. In theory, this should work on any object passed to it.